# Object on both sides of the grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this code to place the walls, it works pretty well, the only problem with it is, that the wall (prefabs height is 4) is placed on the both side of the grid - like the half of wall is on the grid, and the another half under it, how can I fix it?

```
bool creating;
public GameObject start;
public GameObject end;

public GameObject wallPrefab;
GameObject wall;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) 
    {
        getInput();
    }
}

void getInput()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        setStart();
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        setEnd();
    }
    else
    {
        if (creating)
        {
            adjust();
        }
    }

}


void setStart()
{
    creating = true;
    start.transform.position = getWorldPoint();
    wall = (GameObject)Instantiate(wallPrefab, start.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
}


void setEnd()
{
    creating = false;
    end.transform.position = getWorldPoint();
}



void adjust()
{
    end.transform.position = getWorldPoint();
    adjustWall();
}

void adjustWall()
{
    start.transform.LookAt(end.transform.position);
    end.transform.LookAt(start.transform.position);
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(start.transform.position, end.transform.position);
    wall.transform.position = start.transform.position + distance / 2 * start.transform.forward;
    wall.transform.rotation = start.transform.rotation;
    wall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(wall.transform.localScale.x, wall.transform.localScale.y, distance);
}


Vector3 getWorldPoint()
{
    Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        return hit.point;
    }
    return Vector3.zero;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it might help out readers of this question if you provided an image (or even a GIF) of this problem happening, so it's easier for us to understand. (We don't have the same experience and knowledge of this project as you.)

Comment: It looks like this after the placement: http://imgur.com/yMAwlvB (like 2 meters on the grid, 2 under it) and what I want is to have 4 meters of wall on the grid

Comment: Do you need to put brackets in wall.transform.position = start.transform.position + distance / 2 * start.transform.forward; as the calculation of this would be sequential? So if you want to do distance / 2 first then put it in a round bracket.

Comment: @artur47wien It looks like the issue is that your `wallPrefab` object's position is based on the center of the object, and not (as you seem to want) the bottom. If you made this object yourself, open up the 3D modeller application and change its pivot/origin to be on the bottom. If this is a Unity shape, nest the shape within an empty GameObject and move it upwards, such that its bottom matches with the container object's position. And if neither of those are the situation, please edit your question with more details!

Comment: @Serlite yeah i tried this but it didn't really work - distance wasn't calculate correctly after that. anyway, I managed to do it in code

Comment: @artur47wien Interesting - well, feel free to post your own answer to your question - you can self-accept after a day to mark the question as solved, if you feel the knowledge would be useful to others.